# defining new functions such that their names have a normal font

Tags: fonts, macros

There are predefined functions somewhere such that when you use them in default theorem environments, their names appear in a normal (non-italicized) font. I want to be able to define my own functions and have this same effect. Here is an example of what I've been doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\dom}[1]{\text{dom}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
function has normal font: $\sin(0)$ \\
function does not have normal font: $\dom{f}$
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `\DeclareMathOperator` to accomplish this, as explained [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-newfunction.html).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're looking for `\DeclareMathOperator`

Answer (score 0):

Use `\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}`.